# JSF tags not rendered

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I am new to JSF, but my JSF tags are not rendered in xhtml file,
i tried out every possible solution, but problem is not solved

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>JSFProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>JSFProject/index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>JSFProject/index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>JSFProject/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>JSFProject/default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>JSFProject/default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>JSFProject/default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>



  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my example.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h:form>
    Some random data: <h:inputText/><br/>  <!-- Textfield ignored -->
    Some other data: <h:inputText/><br/>   <!-- Textfield ignored -->

    </h:form>

</body>
</html>
```

I had spend 3 days to figure out the problem, any help will be welcome

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: url is: http://localhost:8080/JSFProject/exmaple.xhtml
server is Jboss 5.1.0 GA

Comment: sorry the url is http://localhost:8080/JSFProject/example.xhtml

Comment: what _is_ rendered? get the HTML source of the page.

Comment: include the <f:view> tag and see what happens

Answer (score 17):

The symptoms of the JSF components not being parsed at all indicates that the `FacesServlet` hasn't run. This will happen when the request URL doesn't match the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml`. This would mean that the *actual* `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` isn't `*.xhtml` at all. Are you looking into and editing the right `web.xml` you think you are? Is the right `web.xml` been deployed with the webapp into the servletcontainer?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I fixed this by updating below as:-
Already Martin had mentioned in the above. Thanks.

#### web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

#### faces-config.xml

```
<application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: That only applies to JSF 1.x with Facelets 1.x. OP's problem symptoms and the presence of `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` param indicates that he was using JSF 2.x wherein the `FaceletViewHandler` and `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` is unnecessary and you can map the `FacesServlet` just on `*.xhtml` instead of `*.faces`. Mapping `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` would in JSF 1.x have resulted in an infinite forward loop. I believe after all that his `faces-config.xml` was of incorrect version.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
 <h:form>
    Some random data: <h:inputText/><br/>  <!-- Textfield ignored -->
    Some other data: <h:inputText/><br/>   <!-- Textfield ignored -->

    </h:form>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

I've included the JSF `<f:view>` tag

Comment: This won't help. He's using Facelets where `f:view` isn't mandatory, not JSP. And even then, if he was using JSP, a missing `f:view` would have caused JSF to throw an `IllegalStateException` when it encounters a component without a parent `UINamingContainer` component during parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Man, you haven't set the `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` context parameter. The default for `jsf` is `jsp`, so `jsf` will search for `example.jsp` instead of `example.xhtml`. Basically `JSF` replaces the extension of the resource requested with the `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX`.

Use the following and it will work:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: This is true when you're using JSF 1.2 instead of 2.0, but it would have resulted in a 404 when passed through `FacesServlet`, not in an unparsed page. So it can only mean that it's not been passed through `FacesServlet`.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, but he hasn't told us which version of JSF is using. Also he hasn't clarified what he means by rendered. Maybe he gets a 404 and he hasn't told us. This is what I consider.

Comment: not that it would still matter, but if you change the version in faces-config to 2.0 from your original 1.2 i bet it will work

Answer (score 0):

Do you have faces-config.xml in place that declares Facelets as view handler?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd" version="1.2">
<application>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

Don't forget about javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX parameter to be set to .xhtml as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your web-inf/lib :

jsf-api-2.0.9.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar
jsf-impl-2.0.4-b09.jar
jstl-1.2.jar

without jsf-facelets*.jar, you won't be able to render the jsf view.

And, following should be in your web.xml :

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsf/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Without above two url-pattern, tomcat won't be able to map .xhtml file properly.

And, faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

</faces-config>
```