# MyFaces stopped working properly

Tags: java, jsf-2, myfaces, apache-tomee

I am developing a JSF web application using Netbeans 7.3.1, running on Apache TomEE 1.5.2, which bundles MyFaces 2.1.10, and I am additionally using PrimeFaces 3.5 for some fancy tags.

I must have broken something somewhere, because until yesterday everything went OK, then today when I tried to deploy my application it failed to render `<h:outputText />` while rendering correctly all Primefaces tags. The `<h:form>` tag is rendered as well.

**UPDATE:**
Also `<h:inputText/>` is rendered correctly, but the `value` attribute is ignored there as in `<h:outputText/>`.

Moreover, until yesterday my managed beans worked properly without the `implements Serializable` declaration, while today I get an exception if I don't add it.

I checked these responses, but no one of them seems to apply to my situation: [JSF tags not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328959/jsf-tags-not-rendered), [JSF tags not rendered as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207616/jsf-tags-not-being-rendered-as-html), [JSF tags not rendering JSF tags not rendering - FacesServlet not working maybe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764204/jsf-tags-not-rendering-facesservlet-not-working-maybe). In particular, in these cases the problem seemed to be that the pages were not parsed at all, but in my case the page is partially parsed.

I prepared a small test case inside my application to show this behaviour. This is my `faces-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">

</faces-config>
```

And my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <description>Pannello di amministrazione di FiatLux</description>
    <display-name>Pannello Amministrazione FiatLux</display-name>
    <distributable/>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>Default servlet</description>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is the example page `example.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:outputText value="Example value text" />
            <h:outputText>Text between opening and closing tags</h:outputText>
            <p:pickList id="outPickList"
                        value="#{exampleBean.data}"
                        var="obj"
                        itemLabel="#{obj}" 
                        itemValue="#{obj}">
            </p:pickList>
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{exampleBean.updateAction}" value="Submit"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the backing bean, `ExampleBean.java`:

```
package com.ipssconsulting.fl.admininterface.presentation;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "exampleBean")
public class ExampleBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 89900876464743497L;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExampleBean.class);

    private DualListModel<String> data;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        String[] initData = {
            "Primo", "Secondo", "Terzo"
        };
        data = new DualListModel();
        data.setSource(Arrays.asList(initData));
    }

    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public DualListModel<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void updateAction() {
        logger.info("Clicked");
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(DualListModel<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I prepared a [screenshot](http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/729/3yo.png) with the results.

The PrimeFaces pick list works properly, the text between the `<h:outputText>`[...]`</h:outputText>` is rendered, I believe because the tags are simply removed, but the one using the `value` attribute is not. A similar behaviour happens in all the other pages of my application.

What did I do that could result in such behaviour? What could be the cause?