# JSF tags not rendered in online web server only

Tags: jsf, tags, webserver

I am using JSF 2.2.9 and tomcat 8.0 in my local everything works just fine. One i uploaded my content to Online web server. In the welcome file the JSF components doesnt render.

Searching for solution from quiet long time.Please help

url used ins mydomain.com/home.xhtml

Please find web.xml

```
    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


and XHTML below:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>


Please help :( stuck from a long time..
```

Comment: "*Doesn't render*" means what? Does JSF render the original source file? (Using `/faces/*` in JSF 2.x.x, only adds confusion. Also insist upon using new namespaces introduced in JSF 2.2).

Comment: Hi Tiny, Thanks for your response so I need to use these below namespace is it?  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"  Doesn't render means when the components are not being resolved to html. When I check the view source it shows <h:commandButton> <h:commandlink> etc.,

Comment: "*If JSF tags are not been parsed, then it simply means that the request has not been passed through the `FacesServlet`*". See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2207938/1391249) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3331938/1391249).

Comment: Hi Tiny, The same code works fine in my local tomcat server. localhost:8080/appname.  While the same thing when deployed it is domain.com/welcomefile.xhtml. I am not understanding where I am going wrong could you please help?

Comment: I found solution for this problem. It is not problem with faces servlet. Apache doesn't know how to parse .xhtml files so we need to add *.xhtml ajp3 in cp_mount.conf of apache. Then everything works fine